# HTML5 formdata: read image data from remote server

Tags: html, file-upload, multipartform-data, fileapi

does someone know, is it possible read image to binary from remote URL.
I know that File API give us possibility read as binary file from our local system. 
But i cant find info about reading from remote URL. Maybe even i can read this info from browser cache, after i load this info from to  or else?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem, make a img tag with your url as SRC.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

This function was found on [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Use it like

```
var img = new Image();
img.load = function(){
    var data = getBase64Image(this);
};
img.src= "my IMAGE URL";
```

Or use your own img tag from your HTML

Comment: Thank you for unsver, but its looks like i cant use function toDataUrl   if i load img to canvas from remote server.
and i think i have several variants to solve this:
- maybe use my own proxies for images
- maybe use Yahoo pipes somehow